# Java: How to add MULTIPLE HashSets into a PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, size, priority-queue, hashset

this is probably a really trivial question but how do you add multiple HashSets into a PriorityQueue?

I tried this:

```
      PriorityQueue<HashSet<Integer>> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<HashSet<Integer>>();

      priorityQueue.add(new HashSet<Integer>());
      priorityQueue.add(new HashSet<Integer>());

      System.out.println(priorityQueue.size());
```

and this:

```
  PriorityQueue<HashSet<Integer>> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<HashSet<Integer>>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
    priorityQueue.add(new HashSet<Integer>());
  }
```

but I'm getting an error that says HashSet cannot be cast to a Comparable:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:652)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:647)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:344)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:321)
    at attempt1.PQTest.main(PQTest.java:11)
```

Comment: "[The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.\[...\] A priority queue relying on natural ordering also **does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)."

Comment: To have a priority you have to be able to say which should come first.

Answer (score 0):

From [Java documentation page for PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. (...) A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).

`HashSet` does not implement `Comparable` because it can't really know how your HashSets should be compared, hence you get a `ClassCastException`. So you have to create a class implementing [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in which you will order those HashSets by some criteria and supply its instance to the PriorityQueue constructor.